# Kibana Self Signed Certificate behind Proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We deployed Kibana and Elasticsearch behind a proxy. The problem is the certificate is always marked as self-signed and rejected.

```
Mar 13 09:53:53 elastic kibana[52936]: [2023-03-13T09:53:53.063+00:00][ERROR][plugins.fleet] Failed to fetch latest version of synthetics from registry: Error connecting to package registry: request to https://epr.elastic.co/search?package=synthetics&prerelease=true&kibana.version=8.6.2 failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

The important parts in our kibana config looks like this:

```
...
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities["/etc/kibana/ca-root.crt"]
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none      # tried full and certificate
xpack.fleet.registryProxyUrl: http://proxy-url
...
```

The environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` is also set.
We also added all certificates to the ubuntu vm and with curl everything works and the certificates are correct.

We are using version 8.6.2.

Am I missing something in the config?